# Prove that $(x^3 - x)(2x^2 + 5x - 3)$ is divisible by $5$ without using induction

Tags: divisibility

I've factorised the equation to $x(x+1)(x-1)(2x-1)(x+3)$ and I notice it has $3$ consecutive numbers, a missing one and then the next consecutive number not sure how to use this to prove the required divisibility.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You've got to edit this and make clear that you mean that $x$ is an integer.

Comment: There were no restrictions for x in the question and it was an exam question so I'm not sure either.

Comment: Bad question in that case. It makes no sense otherwise. The polynomial is divisible by $5$ if we allow rational coefficients, but not if we insist on integer coefficients.

Comment: Hint: $x=5k+r$ with $r=0,1,2,3,4$. Deal with these five cases.

Comment: $\!\!\bmod 5\!:\ 2x-1 \equiv 2(x+2)\,$ so the product is congruent to  twice the product of $5$ consecutive integers, so it is $\equiv 0\,$ by the linked dupe. $\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you says, we have
$$(x-1)x(x+1)(x+3) (2x-1) ~,$$
so we just need to proof that:
when $(x-1)x(x+1)(x+3) \not \equiv 0\pmod 5$, $2x-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

$(x-1)x(x+1)(x+3) \not \equiv 0\pmod 5$ means that $x+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ so $x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$.then $2x-1 \equiv 6-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

Q.E.D

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).